# Chinese PDF Font STSong-Light not working with Jasper Report

Tags: fonts, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

Im using Jasper Report 6.6.0 and want to use the Chinese Font STSong-Light pdf font name in my pdf as such:

```
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="180" height="19" uuid="d13475a2-7abb-40ed-ad4c-29d9fbb8a510"/>
            <textElement>
                <font pdfFontName="STSong-Light" pdfEncoding="UniGB-UCS2-H" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{UserName}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

I also added itextpdf and itext-asian to the Java build path in JasperReports
[image]

However, when i try to preview it in PDF mode, it shows the following error.
[image]